# radio button onclick form submit to two different page action is not working in firefox

Tags: javascript, php

This is code for onclick radio button form submit and when click to different radio button form action should be changed. This code is properly working in chrome and opera but it is not working in firefox. This is form page.
Please help to run code in firefox also.

```
<form action="" method="post" name="form1">
    <ul class="list-group">
        <li class="list-group-item">
            <div class="radio">
                <label>
                    <input type="radio" name="optradio" value="yes" onclick="this.form.submit()">
                        <span style="margin-left:40px"></span>
                        <img src="../../pum/PayUMoney_logo.png">
                </label>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li class="list-group-item">
            <div class="radio">
                <label>
                    <input type="radio" name="optradio" value='no' onclick="this.form.submit()" >
                    <span style="margin-left:40px"></span>
                    <img src="../../pum/atom_logo_1.png" style=" height: 35px; width: 163px;">
                </label>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">

jQuery(document).ready(function($) 
{
    var form = $('form[name="form1"]'),
    radio = $('input[name="optradio"]'),
    choice = '';
    radio.change(function(e) 
    {
        choice = this.value;
        if (choice === 'yes') 
        {
            form.attr('action', 'hello.php');
            form.attr('target,_'blank');
        } 
        else 
        {
            form.attr('action', 'another.php');
        }
    });
});

</script>
```

Comment: it seems like you are missing a quote on form.attr('target,_'blank'); should be form.attr('target','_blank');

Comment: after correction code is not running

Comment: Why you don't do thant on submit? https://api.jquery.com/submit/

Comment: Due To we have to add this code in Payment gateway coding

Answer (score 5):

You have onclick function called on html but that function is never defined. And you have radio.change function defined in js, which i assume you want to work. Why don't you try and remove that onclick function and see what happens. Your html code would be:

```
<input type="radio" name="optradio" value="yes">
```

See if that solves your problem

Comment: <form action="" method="post" name="form1">
         <ul class="list-group">
           <li class="list-group-item">
                <div class="radio">
                    <input type="radio" name="optradio" value="yes">
                                     </div>
                     </li>
            <li class="list-group-item">
              <div class="radio">
                <input type="radio" name="optradio" value="no">
              </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
            <input type="submit" name="sub" value="Submit" class="btn btn-info">
            </form>